# Meteor HTTP.post - Twitter Status Update - Bad Data Authentication

Tags: meteor, twitter-oauth

What's wrong here?

I'm confused about how to generate all the tokens to post a status update.
If someone can post steps that would be great.

I have no idea what to do to create the signature as per:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

What else is missing?

```
HTTP.post("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json",                      
{   
    headers: {
               'Authorization': "OAuth",
               "content-type":"application/json"
             },
    params:  {
               "oauth_access_token": Meteor.user().services.twitter.accessToken,
               "oauth_access_token_secret":Meteor.user().services.twitter.accessTokenSecret,
               "consumer_key": "<insert key here>",
               "consumer_secret": "<insert secret here>",
               "oauth_nonce": randomString(32, '#aA'),
               "oauth_version": "1.0"},
               data:{"status" : text}
             },
    function(err){
        console.log('after posting:' + err)
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you spot that the page you posted [links](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature) to an explanation of how to generate a signature? This looks quite complicated and I'd expect there to be a library method you can use to perform these steps. Would be interested to know how this question gets answered fully.

Comment: how are you handling the authorizing of the user? are you using the "accounts-twitter" meteor package? and a quick search on atmosphere (meteor package manager) showed these two twitter library's https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/twit, https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/codebird-js

Comment: Yes I'm using accounts-twitter. I tried twit. It doesn't work. There's some error message like unknown function. I think I may have raises an issue on github already